# multiple foreign keys as primary key postgres, should I do it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is one of those: why I should or why I should not.

So my books app has reviews, but one user must not review the same book more than one time. In my point of view makes sense to create a table for the reviews and make the user_id and the book_id (ISBN) as the PRIMARY KEY for the reviews table. But, could it be a problem at some point if the application gets too many reviews, for example, could that decision slow the queries?

I am using postgres and I am not sure if the following code is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id PRIMARY KEY SERIAL,
    user_name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    pass_hash VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE books(
    book_id PRIMARY KEY BIGINT,
    author VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    year INT NOT NULL CHECK (year > 1484),
    review_count INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    avrg_score FLOAT,
);

CREATE TABLE reviews(
    user_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(user_id) NOT NULL
    book_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES books(book_id) NOT NULL
    score INT NOT NULL CHECK (score > 0, score < 11)
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, user_id)

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid design choice.

You have a many-to-many relationship between books and users, which is represented by the `reviews` table. Having a compound primary key based on two foreign keys lets you enforce referential integrity (a given tuple may only appear once), and at the same time provides a primary key for the table.

Another option would be to have a surrogate primary key for the bridge table. This could make things easier if you need to reference the `reviews` from another table, but you would still need a unique constraint on both foreign key columns for integrity, so this would actually result in extra space being used.

When it comes to your code, it has a few issues:

- the `primary key` keyword goes after the datatype
- the `check` constraint is incorrectly formed
- missing or additional commas here and there

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    user_name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    pass_hash VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE books(
    book_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    author VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    year INT NOT NULL CHECK (year > 1484),
    review_count INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    avrg_score FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE reviews(
    user_id INT REFERENCES users(user_id) NOT NULL,
    book_id INT REFERENCES books(book_id) NOT NULL,
    score INT NOT NULL CHECK (score > 0 and score < 11),
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, user_id)

);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really enlightening! =D

Answer (score 1):

I the above is good but I would drop columns review_count and avrg_score from books. These are derivable when needed. If needed for your application then instead of storing these create a view to derive them. This avoids the always complicated process of maintaining running values:

```
create view books_vw as 
    select b.book_id  
         , b.author 
         , b.title 
         , b.year 
         , count(r.*) review_count 
         , avg(r.score) avrg_score
      from books   b 
      left join reviews r
        on r.book_id = b.book_id
     group by 
           b.book_id  
         , b.author 
         , b.title 
         , b.year                  
 ;
```

Comment: Ow, good points, I didn't think about that issue on getting data. I think that makes a lot of sense since the database will work quite better. Thank you! =D